# How much zakat should be paid?

Tags: sunni, zakat

I want to know If I am a working lady

1. Can I pay Zakat for myself and my siblings? Is it halal or haram??
2. How much amount should be paid by me according to Indian currency per person ??

I'm a Sunni muslim. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Salam Shahida,

```
Qs1. Can I pay Zakat for myself and my siblings? Is it halal or haram?
```

Yes, You can pay your own zakat and also you can pay for your siblings if they give you permission.

```
Qs2. How much amount should be paid by me according to Indian currency per person ?
```

Zakat is not a fixed amount of money per person. Zakat is calculated depending upon someone's savings. If you are eligible to pay zakat then you need to pay 2.5% annual savings that are Zakatable. You can find several zakat calculators online.

Hope this answer helps you.

Regards,